# How to create iterrator for string list

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I have a list with string elements, and in the end I want to recieve:

```
a hello
b hello
c hello
d hello
```

And I've got this code:

```
list=['a','b','c','d']

class Iterator:

    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start=start
        self.end=end

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.start += ' hello'
        if self.start == list[-1]:
          raise StopIterration 
        return self.start

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for item in Iterator(list[0], list[-1]):
        print(item)
```

However, the methond `__next__` CANNOT MOVE FROM `list[0]` to `list[1]`, and the python began to be crazy and add billion of "`hello`" to the `list[0]`, and can't even stop the program, so it's the hell's loop now. 
Problems are:

1. Adding billon of "hello" to `list[0]`, not moving to `list[1]`.
2. Doesn't finish the program at all, despite I wrote what is a condition for finish.

[image]

Comment: You're adding "hello" to `self.start`. Your stop condition is if `self.start` equals the last value in the list. "hello" doesn't appear once in the list, so that condition will never be true…

Comment: Why create a custom iterator class here? Just use a generator function, or if you `import itertools`, I'm pretty sure you just want `zip(mylist, itertools.repeat('hello'))`. Not exactly sure what your `start` and `end` parameters are supposed to do...

Comment: Given that you pass just the first and last elements of your list to `Iterator`, how can it possibly know about the intermediate items?

Comment: @quamrana good point...of course it could use the hard-coded global name but that is just terrible design...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Ha, ha. Yes, look, I'm ROTFL. Anyway, the solution is to simply make `Iterator` a wrapper around the parameter. (Alternatively see the answer from chepner).

Comment: btw Don't use `list` as the name of a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your instance of `Iterator` isn't tied to the list at all; it's irrelevant that you *used* the list to create the instance; `Iterator.__init__` only saw two string values.

`__init__` needs a reference to the list itself for use by `__next__`. Further, `hello` is something you append to the return value of `__next__`, not something you need to append to internal state every time you call `__next__`.

```
list=['a','b','c','d']

class Iterator:

    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst
        self.start = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            value = self.lst[self.start]
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration
        self.start += 1

        return value + ' hello'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for item in Iterator(list):
        print(item)
```

Comment: Thank you, kind sir, you've just saved me from heart attack from nervous system) Everywhere are examples just with working with iterators on numbers, which is irrelevant to strings.